# How to count unique actions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Goal: I would like to be able to run a report that shows, or see somehow in Google Analytics, how many unique users used a certain feature of our app in a given month.

Problem: Currently our analytics show the total number of times a feature was used (e.g. page visit), not how many people are using it. Some users use a feature many times a day, some never, but I only see how many times it was used in total.

Setup: Each feature is encoded into an URL by Event Category and Event Action. E.g. MyApp/File/Export, MyApp/File/Import, MyApp/Object/Create, MyApp/Object/Move, MyApp/Object/Destroy, etc. There is also a category called "MachineID" and it's set to a unique ID for each user such as MyApp/MachineID/0000, MyApp/MachineID/0001, etc.

Am I right in assuming there is no way we can merge/sort/filter the data together to yield what I want? I don't see how to associate the unique user URL with the URLs for features.

Would adding the MachineID to the end of the URL for each feature as a parameter allow me to generate the info I need? Or is all this impossible anyway within GA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm blindly assuming that the GA interface for app tracking looks the same like for web tracking.

So you get want you want by creating a new segment -> filter : users : include : screen name = "myfeature".

This will get you a segment with all users that have looked at the screenname "myfeature" in the selected timeframe, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for posting! Isn't screen name the same as page URLs though? My issue currently is that the concept of a unique visitor in our GA data is too unique because our utma cookie changes every time the user launches. So we're trying to use a machine ID event. But in checking into screen name I think I might have found a way to keep our user identifier the same between launches :-)